# Elementor Form Validation for fields with same type and different IDs

Tags: wordpress, forms, validation, elementor

I have built a form in elementor which has two separate fields [Country Code] and [Contact Number] both having type "Tel". I'd like to add different validations for these fields as the country code can be a 2/3 digit number and the contact number can be 10 digit number.

The code I have, currently validates based on the type i.e tel and not ID. I'd like to have a code which can identify ID and set the validation.

Here's the current validation code

```
add_action('elementor_pro/forms/validation/tel', function( $field, $record, $ajax_handler ) {
//remove native validation
/**
 * @var \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Module $forms_module
 */
$forms_module = \ElementorPro\Plugin::instance()->modules_manager->get_modules( 'forms' );
remove_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/validation/tel', [ $forms_module->fields_registrar->get('tel') , 'validation' ] );

// run your own validation, ex:
if ( empty( $field['value'] ) ) {
    return;
}

if ( preg_match( '/^[0-9]{10}$/', $field['value'] ) !== 1 ) {
    write_log($field['value']);
    write_log(preg_match( '/^[0-9]{10}$/', $field['value'] ));
    $ajax_handler->add_error( $field['id'], __( 'Phone number must contain only numbers or +', 'text-domain' ));
}
```

}, 9, 3 );

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/render_field/tel', function( $item, $item_index, $form ) {
//remove native render
/**
 * @var \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Module $forms_module
 */
$forms_module = \ElementorPro\Plugin::instance()->modules_manager->get_modules( 'forms' );

remove_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/render_field/tel', [$forms_module->fields_registrar->get('tel') , 'field_render' ], 10, 3 );

// add your custom render ex:
$form->add_render_attribute( 'input' . $item_index, 'class', 'elementor-field-textual' );
$form->add_render_attribute( 'input' . $item_index, 'pattern', '/^[0-9]{10}$/' );
$form->add_render_attribute( 'input' . $item_index, 'title', __( 'Phone number must contain only numbers or +', 'text-domain' ) );
echo '<input size="1" ' . $form->get_render_attribute_string( 'input' . $item_index ) . '>';
```

}, 9, 3 );